# Having difficulty modifying JSON object in PHP Script

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop

Hi we have been trying to create a game for a school project and cannot figure out how to modify the JSON code through PHP.

Here is the PHP code we made to modify an object's value from the key,

```
    $json_object = file_get_contents('players.json');
    $data = json_decode($json_object);

    foreach($data as $key)
    {
        $data['winning_cards'] = [1,2,3];
    }
    $json_object = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('players.json', $json_object);
```

After completing we now have 0 in front in the JSON file,

```
{"0":{"username":"test_username","character":"TEST","position":"6","current_turn":false,"cards":[],"winning_cards":[]},"winning_cards":[1,2,3]}
```

We want the code as is without the "0" and the existing winning_cards with the new array value from the PHP script. It is getting placed afterwards and changing the JSON file completely.

Comment: What does the JSON look like before you modify it?

Comment: @Dave2kool4skool did you check my answer? is that helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you've stored JSON in the **player.json** file like below format,

**playes.json**

```
[{"username":"test_username","character":"TEST","position":"6","current_turn":false,"cards":[],"winning_cards":[]}]
```

Then you need to decode it as an array with the 2nd parameter of `json_decode()` as `true` which make an `array` currently on your code it returns as an `object`. So let's do it this way,

```
<?php
$json_object = '[{"username":"test_username","character":"TEST","position":"6","current_turn":false,"cards":[],"winning_cards":[]}]';
$data = json_decode($json_object,true); # see the 2nd parameter
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    $data[$key]['winning_cards'] = [1,2,3];
}
$json_object = json_encode($data);
echo $json_object;
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/iCGtO